# proxysql SHUNNED servers in hostgroup

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, galera, proxysql

I have 2 proxysql(2.0.13) + keepalived in front of a 3-node galera-cluster, and 2 of the galera-nodes appeaers as "SHUNNED" in my hostgroup 10.
I do not know why they appear as "SHUNNED" and they are never recovered.

So i was hoping that somebody here can help me bring the shunned servers back in the loop.

What i've tried:
- Set the var mysql-shun_on_failures = 5000 & mysql-shun_recovery_time_sec = 10
- reboot the proxysql nodes

I have made connections to the hostgroup 10, and did some queries, to trigger a recovery, but they are still shunned.

Here's some info from proxysql

```
Servers:
Admin> select * from runtime_mysql_servers;
+--------------+-----------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
| hostgroup_id | hostname  | port | gtid_port | status  | weight | compression | max_connections | max_replication_lag | use_ssl | max_latency_ms | comment |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+
| 10           | 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 0         | SHUNNED | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 20           | 10.4.4.22 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 30           | 10.4.4.23 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 30           | 10.4.4.22 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 30           | 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 10           | 10.4.4.23 | 3306 | 0         | ONLINE  | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
| 10           | 10.4.4.22 | 3306 | 0         | SHUNNED | 1      | 0           | 1000            | 0                   | 0       | 0              |         |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+---------+


Hostgroups:
Admin> select * from runtime_mysql_galera_hostgroups;
+------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| writer_hostgroup | backup_writer_hostgroup | reader_hostgroup | offline_hostgroup | active | max_writers | writer_is_also_reader | max_transactions_behind | comment            |
+------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| 10               | 20                      | 30               | 9999              | 1      | 1           | 1                     | 30                      | galera-hostgroup-1 |
+------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+

Status:
Admin> select hostgroup,srv_host,status,ConnUsed,MaxConnUsed,Queries,Latency_us from stats.stats_mysql_connection_pool order by srv_host;
+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+---------+------------+
| hostgroup | srv_host  | status  | ConnUsed | MaxConnUsed | Queries | Latency_us |
+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+---------+------------+
| 10        | 10.4.4.21 | SHUNNED | 0        | 0           | 0       | 289        |
| 30        | 10.4.4.21 | ONLINE  | 0        | 0           | 0       | 289        |
| 20        | 10.4.4.21 | ONLINE  | 0        | 0           | 0       | 289        |
| 10        | 10.4.4.22 | SHUNNED | 0        | 0           | 0       | 281        |
| 30        | 10.4.4.22 | ONLINE  | 0        | 0           | 0       | 281        |
| 20        | 10.4.4.22 | ONLINE  | 0        | 0           | 0       | 281        |
| 10        | 10.4.4.23 | ONLINE  | 1        | 1           | 106     | 277        |
| 30        | 10.4.4.23 | ONLINE  | 0        | 0           | 0       | 277        |
+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+---------+------------+

My ping-log:
Admin> select * from monitor.mysql_server_ping_log order by time_start_us DESC limit 0,10;
+-----------+------+------------------+----------------------+------------+
| hostname  | port | time_start_us    | ping_success_time_us | ping_error |
+-----------+------+------------------+----------------------+------------+
| 10.4.4.23 | 3306 | 1597916943398296 | 257                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 1597916943298413 | 232                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.22 | 3306 | 1597916943198499 | 276                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.22 | 3306 | 1597916935355114 | 220                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.23 | 3306 | 1597916935277079 | 259                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 1597916935199034 | 232                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.22 | 3306 | 1597916927359456 | 175                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 1597916927278902 | 242                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.23 | 3306 | 1597916927198335 | 302                  | NULL       |
| 10.4.4.21 | 3306 | 1597916919324515 | 189                  | NULL       |
+-----------+------+------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

Thank you all..

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar issue where an instance in one infrequently used pool gets shunned, but passes all its checks.  The only thing I've found to bring it back online is to use `load mysql servers to runtime` on one of the ProxySQL cluster nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why they are marked as "shunned":

My hostgroup-configuration has the max_writers = 1 - which means that ONLY one of my 3 writers (in my writer hostgroup) should be available at the time, and the 2 others should be standing by, so the can take over if the current writer should fail.

It is explained very well here - look under "ProxySQL 2.x Support for Galera Cluster"
https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-run-and-configure-proxysql-20-mysql-galera-cluster-docker.